# Whats the best way to keep a user signed in after their session ends?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working on a simple login page for a class and was planning on using cookies to keep users logged in (if they choose) after closing their browser. I used a checkbox input button as a case to set a cookie. After a user goes to the login page and signs in I send them to a script to check for valid username and passwords where I also check if the button was used

```
  #QotD.php

  if(isset($_GET['signed_in']))      #check box value
  if($_GET['signed_in']=="on"){ 
  if(isset($_GET['username']))
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    setcookie('username',$username,time()+10000);#cookie set with username
  }
```

What I thought to do was to have a conditional statement at the beginning of the login page file checking whether a cookie is set and if it is go directly to the main page.

```
#QotD_homepage.php
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
header("Location: main_page.php");
exit();
}
```

The problem is that it seems to keep the user signed in whether they check the box off or not. I tried adding a button to unset the cookie but it didn't work. Is there a more efficient way to handle cookies in this manner?

Comment: Conditional statement is wron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, for signing in a user, you are going to want to use the `POST` action method as it hides the information from the url. The `GET` method contains the information in the url and can be easy copied and hacked.

Secondly, you if statements should look like this

```
if(isset($_GET['username']))
{ 
  $username = $_GET['username'];
  # do something with username...
  if(isset($_GET['signed_in']) && $_GET['signed_in']=="on")
    setcookie('username',$username,time()+10000);
  }
}
```

To solve your question regarding why user is being logged in every time, even when you don't set the cookie, the reason is probably because you have not `unset` the cookie. This is usualy done via a `logout` page.

Create a logout page with the code:

```
setcookie('username', null, 1);
```

Then run this page every time you wish to unset the cookie to test the login without ticking the checkbox.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I actually did have a log out page! I set a button on the page the user goes after logging in that would go to small php file that unset the cookie with a header method that redirects the user to the login page but the conditional statement checking for a cookie seems to still be reading as true and sends me back to the after login page.

Comment: Did you try changing the if statements?

Comment: Check boxes are complicated html inputs. Try the code with a radio button. If it works, then you know it has to do with the way you handle the check box data rather than your cookie code.

Comment: Yes it helped in that I can use the log out button without being sent back to the main user page, but it's still redirecting even when I don't check the box.

Comment: Try: `if(!empty($_COOKIE['username']))`

Comment: I got it working the way I wanted and I went back to change from get to post and now it doesnt seem to be reading the user input and returns a unindentified index error :? NVM I FIXD IT

Comment: If my code fixed it before the `GET` to `POST` change, can you please select this as the answer. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If conditional statement is wrong.Fix it by ending it with end if or using {} brackets. Use the code below

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['signed_in'])) {     #check box value
  if($_GET['signed_in']=="on"){ 
  if(isset($_GET['username']))
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    setcookie('username',$username,time()+10000);#cookie set with username
  }
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['signed_in'])) :     #check box value
  if($_GET['signed_in']=="on"){ 
  if(isset($_GET['username']))
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    setcookie('username',$username,time()+10000);#cookie set with username
  }
endif;
?>
```

Hope this helps you